# Pandas Grouped Bar Chart Displayed in Descending Order

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have a grouped bar chart of 2 columns `Gender` and `Churn Category`. I want to sort the chart in descending order so that it displays as Competitor, Dissatisfaction, Attitude, etc.

I tried to put an ascending command at the end, but received an error message.

My code:

```
pd.crosstab(df['Churn Category'], df['Gender']).plot(kind="bar", figsize=(15, 5))

plt.title("Frequency of Churn Category by Gender")
plt.xlabel("Churn Category")
plt.ylabel("Count")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to take the `value_counts()` of the `Churn Category` column and use that to construct an [ordered categorical data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html).  Taking the `value_counts()` of a column will return a series ordered descendingly.  The index of this series can be used to create the ordered categorical data type.

Once that is done you can set the data type of the `Churn Category` column in the original dataframe to be the ordered categorical type you just created.

Pandas will now respect that order when you `crosstab`.

Here's a minimum reproducible example of that approach:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Churn Category':
            ['Competitor', 'Dissatisfaction', 'Attitude', 'Other', 'Price', 'Dissatisfaction', 'Attitude', 'Price',
             'Other', 'Competitor', 'Dissatisfaction', 'Competitor', 'Competitor', 'Attitude', 'Attitude', 'Attitude',
             'Attitude', 'Attitude', 'Attitude'],
        'Gender':
            ['Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female',
             'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male']
    }
)

# value_counts defaultly returns a descending order.
churn_category_counts = df['Churn Category'].value_counts().index
ordered_categorical_churn_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=churn_category_counts)
df['Churn Category'] = df['Churn Category'].astype(ordered_categorical_churn_type)
pd.crosstab(df['Churn Category'], df['Gender']).plot(kind="bar", figsize=(15, 5))

plt.title("Frequency of Churn Category by Gender")
plt.xlabel("Churn Category")
plt.ylabel("Count")
plt.show()
```